# Click Marker To draw Direction

Tags: android, json, google-maps, directions

i wanted to make direction from my current position to marker.
when i tapping marker then direction will show on map.

This problem is when i cliked on marker the direction not show. i must click near the marker, then the marker will show up.

this is the code
Main activity

```
http://pastebin.com/5ed2NfLx
```

Direction JSON

```
http://pastebin.com/jKTCbybk

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;
        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);

                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /**
    * Method to decode polyline points
    * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
    * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                                 (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem, cause I am looking for the same answer?